# Dynamic Menu, Ajax, Ruby

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, drop-down-menu

Hey folks a nooby noob here,

My application has Dynamic Drop down menus for Category and Subcategory. When a category is selected the corresponding subcategory will change and display the category's subcategories - I have that set. But what I would like to accomplish is to hide the subcategory menu until a category is selected.

My Code i'm using for menus:

```
StaticPage Controller

          def update_subcategories
            # updates categories and subcategories based on product type selected
            category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
            # map to name and id for use in our options_for_select
            @subcategories = category.subcategories.map{|a| [a.name, a.id]}.insert(0, "Select a Product")
          end
```

View staticpage>home

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label 'Choose a Product:' %>
      <%= f.collection_select :category_id,  @categories,  :id, :name, {:prompt   => "Select a Category"}, {:id => 'categories_select'} %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label 'Choose a brand:' %>
      <%= f.collection_select :subcategory_id, @subcategories, :id, :name, {:prompt   => "Select an Product"}, {:id => 'subcategories_select'} %>
    </div>


<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var categories = '#categories_select';
    var subcategories = '#subcategories';


    $('#categories_select').change(function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "<%= update_subcategories_path %>",
        data: {
          category_id : $('#categories_select').val()
        },
        dataType: "script"
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

View staticpage>update_subcategories.js.erb

```
$('#subcategories_select').html("<%= escape_javascript(options_for_select(@subcategories)) %>");
```

Thanks in advance!

---

Update

---

USING @PAVAN SUGGESTION. HOWEVER DROPDOWN SUBCATEGORY MENU SEEMS TO BREAK: 
image of subcat. menu

[image: Subcategory breaking]

Comment: Is it not showing the label ***Choose a brand*** too?

Comment: @Pavan the label is not showing either...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#subcategories_select').hide();

    $('#categories_select').change(function() {
      $('#subcategories_select').show();
      $.ajax({
        url: "<%= update_subcategories_path %>",
        data: {
          category_id : $('#categories_select').val()
        },
        dataType: "script"
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

You don't need these lines `var categories = '#categories_select';` `var subcategories = '#subcategories';`

And also provide **id** `subcategories_select` to the `sub_categories` ***div*** instead to the `sub_categories` `collection_select` otherwise you will end showing the label ***Choose a brand:*** before changing the products `collection_select`.

```
<div class="form-group", id="subcategories_select">
  <%= f.label 'Choose a brand:' %>
  <%= f.collection_select :subcategory_id, @subcategories, :id, :name, {:prompt => "Select an Product"} %>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Pavan! That did it! However, The dropdown menu for subcategory seems to break. I've placed an image up above..